# R: LIME package: get probability change when variable changes?

Tags: r, machine-learning, probability

I have a question about the LIME package. I've made a model with lime like this example from [thomasp85](https://datascienceplus.com/explaining-complex-machine-learning-models-with-lime/) (thank you):

```
devtools::install_github("thomasp85/lime")
setwd("C:/world-happiness-report")
load("data_15_16.RData")
# configure multicore
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

library(caret)
set.seed(42)
index <- createDataPartition(data_15_16$Happiness.Score.l, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train_data <- data_15_16[index, ]
test_data  <- data_15_16[-index, ]
set.seed(42)
model_mlp <- caret::train(Happiness.Score.l ~ .,
                          data = train_data,
                          method = "mlp",
                          trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                                                   number = 10, 
                                                   repeats = 5, 
                                                   verboseIter = FALSE))

library(lime)

explain <- lime(train_data, model_mlp, bin_continuous = TRUE, n_bins = 5, n_permutations = 1000)
pred <- data.frame(sample_id = 1:nrow(test_data),
                   predict(model_mlp, test_data, type = "prob"),
                   actual = test_data$Happiness.Score.l)
pred$prediction <- colnames(pred)[3:5][apply(pred[, 3:5], 1, which.max)]
pred$correct <- ifelse(pred$actual == pred$prediction, "correct", "wrong")

library(tidyverse)
pred_cor <- filter(pred, correct == "correct")
pred_wrong <- filter(pred, correct == "wrong")

test_data_cor %
mutate(sample_id = 1:nrow(test_data)) %>%
  filter(sample_id %in% pred_cor$sample_id) %>%
  sample_n(size = 3) %>%
  remove_rownames() %>%
  tibble::column_to_rownames(var = "sample_id") %>%
  select(-Happiness.Score.l)

test_data_wrong %
mutate(sample_id = 1:nrow(test_data)) %>%
  filter(sample_id %in% pred_wrong$sample_id) %>%
  sample_n(size = 3) %>%
  remove_rownames() %>%
  tibble::column_to_rownames(var = "sample_id") %>%
  select(-Happiness.Score.l)

explanation_cor <- explain(test_data_cor, n_labels = 3, n_features = 5)
explanation_wrong <- explain(test_data_wrong, n_labels = 3, n_features = 5)

plot_features(explanation_wrong, ncol = 3)
```

The plot produces the following exampple for a certain case:
[image]

What I would like to know: is there a way to get numbers on how the probability would change when (for example) `Family` would be higher, so for example:

> Family in this case has level: 0.71. When Family would increase with
>   0.1 this would cause the probability to increase with 0.5%

The reason for this is that I have got the same graph type, and I would like to create additional information of the meaning of the effect that is indicated in the graph.

Any information, also in the form of literature etc would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are asking for counterfactuals.  LIME does not really provides this functionality. It is not their goal. You have to create the counterfactuals manually and submit them to LIME in the same iteration because LIME is non-deterministic -- it selects randomly the neighbors to fit the interpretable model-- so you get different results every time you run it.